# Change antlr lexer parser for supporting "and" and "or" keywords

Tags: parsing, antlr, lexer

I am using ANTLR to create lexer/parser. Expressions can have the format like this

```
if(a==1 || b==2 or c==3 && d==4 and e==5)
```

I have grammar for supporting && and || like this -

```
AND :   '&&'
OR  :   '||'
```

Need to know what changes will be required for supporting keyword "and" and "or".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just list "and" and "or" as alternatives in the definition of `AND` and `OR`

```
AND : '&&' | 'and'
OR  : '||' | 'or'
```

Answer (score 3):

Just add them as alternatives after the existing operators:

```
AND : '&&' | 'and';
OR  : '||' | 'or';
```

Be sure to add these two rules above a possible `IDENTIFIER` rule that could possibly match `"and"` and `"or"` as well. By adding them above an `IDENTIFIER`, the rules `AND` and `OR` get precedence over `IDENTIFIER`.